# Syntax Error when opening Windows Phone Emulator though CMD line

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to open Windows Phone Emulator through CMD line.
I can't figure out what the syntax error is.
This is my CMD line code:

```
C:\Users\Dell>cd..
C:\Users>cd..
C:\>cd "Program Files"
C:\Program Files>cd "Microsoft XDE"
C:\Program Files\Microsoft XDE>cd 1.0
C:\Program Files\Microsoft XDE\1.0>xde
C:\Program Files\Microsoft XDE\1.0>xde "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
Phone\v7.0\Emulation\Images\WM70C1.en-US.bin" /vmid <c3cd7d93-42e7-4b5d-8e6b-0f7
54b773e55>
    // fetching the location of the emulator image
    The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft XDE\1.0>
```

Comment: The error is syntax of the command is incorrect. Error should be in the last line but i cnt figure out.

Comment: i finally managed to correct the syntax error <>={} but it is not launching the emulator though. If i could get any help..

Comment: What version of SDK you are using?